# replace a object in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I try to replace an object from my Array with a string. I use

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;

NSString *oldString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"oldObject"];
NSString *toReplace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newObject"];

NSUInteger index = [self.myArray indexOfObject:oldString];
[self.firstLanguageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:toReplace];
```

But every time I try to replace, the app will crash.

Edit: I logged the "index". I will become a Integer like `2147483647`.

Comment: 2147483647 is NSNotFound. Where is myArray initialized and where is oldString added ?

Comment: BTW - get rid of the needless use of `stringWithFormat:`. Just do `NSString *oldString = @"oldObject";`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because your call to `indexOfObject` returns `NSNotFound`.

`NSNotFound` is a constant that tells you that the `oldString` object is not found in your `self.myArray` dictionary, and as this constant has a value of `(NSUInteger)-1` (which is equivalent to the unsigned value `2147483647` because of integer underflow), value that will obviously crash your app with an "Out of Bounds" exception.

The solution is to test whether the `index != NSNotFound` before using it. Or to make sure that your array `self.myArray` actually contains an object of type `NSString` whose value is `"oldObject"`.

If, given your actual code, you expected `oldObject` to be present in your `self.myArray`, then think again, maybe log the content of `self.myArray` to lookup what it actually contains, and also check that this content is a string.
*(if you see `"oldObject"` when logging the content of your `myArray`, that's probably just the `description` string of the object in your array, so the array does not contain the string `"oldObject"` itself, but an object whose description is `"oldObject"`)*

---

Side note: there is no need to use `stringWithFormat` if you don't use any format placeholder (like `%d` or `%@` etc). You should simply directly use the string constant in that case, no need to dynamically build a string if that string is a constant: simply use `NSString* oldString = @"oldObject"` and `NSString* toReplace = @"newObject"`.